# Pytables check if column exists

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

Is it possible to use Pytables (or Pandas) to detect whether a hdf file's table contains a certain column? To load the hdf file I use:

```
from pandas.io.pytables import HDFStore
# this doesn't read the full file which is good
hdf_store = HDFStore('data.h5', mode='r')
# returns a "Group" object, not sure if this could be used...
hdf_store.get_node('tablename')
```

I could also use Pytables directly instead of Pandas. The aim is not to load all the data of the hdf file as these files are potentially large and I only want to establish whether a certain column exists.

Comment: try this: `hdf_store['tablename'].columns`

Comment: This takes a long time to complete (3GB hdf file), so I guess it's pulling in the complete file. But it returns the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have found a solution, but am unsure of (1) why it works and (2) whether this is a robust solution.

```
import tables
h5 = tables.openFile('data.h5', mode='r')
df_node = h5.root.__getattr__('tablename')
# Not sure why `axis0` contains the column data, but it seems consistent
# with the tested h5 files.
columns = df_node.axis0[:]
```

`columns` contains a `numpy` array with all the column names.

Comment: That is pretty smart! Here is a pandas equivalent: `pd.HDFStore('data.h5').get_node('tablename').axis0[:]`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution doesn't work for me with Pandas 0.20.3 and PyTables 3.3.0 (the HDF file was created using Pandas). However, this works:

```
pd.HDFStore('data.hd5', mode='r').get_node('/path/to/pandas/df').table.colnames
```